# iOS AVPlayer cancel buffering

Tags: ios, streaming, avplayer

If I load an `AVPlayer` with a file from a host with

```
[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

And the "*buffering*" takes longer than the user wants, how do I allow them to cancel it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the correct answer is @Che with:

> If you will call [self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
>   buffering stops. – Che Oct 13 at 14:36

and you do so on the observer listening for the status update from the playerWithPlayerItem.  Thanks All!

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
// pause buffer
[self.playerItem cancelPendingSeeks];
[self.playerItem.asset cancelLoading];
```

Comment: Hi! how do you resume it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a method to directly stop buffering. But you can check the boolean `playbackLikelyToKeepUp` property of the AVPlayerItem to check if the buffer is loading. I not then pause playback on the AVPlayer.

Comment: So if I call  [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem] and set a thread to initialte a time out after say 30 seconds, how to I ensure that when when  [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem]  finally does return it doesn't start playing.  In fact if the user chooses a different stream and initiates it, how do I stop the

Comment: If you will call
 `[self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];`
buffering stops.

Comment: Hey Che, thanks.  So if I instantiate player with 
`self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];`  
In another thread can I issue 
`[self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];` even though control has not returned to the instantiation?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

```
player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage **preferredForwardBufferDuration** of avplayer currentItem. If you want to stop buffering set value to 1 because if you set it to 0 it will be set up automatically

```
self.avPlayer.currentItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration = 1;
```

**From Apple documentation:**
This property defines the preferred forward buffer duration in seconds. If set to 0, the player will choose an appropriate level of buffering for most use cases. Setting this property to a low value will increase the chance that playback will stall and re-buffer, while setting it to a high value will increase demand on system resources.