# How to pause/resume avplayer preload

Tags: ios, video-streaming, buffer, avplayer, audio-streaming

I'm using `AVPlayer` to play video from Internet, is there a way to **pause/resume** preloading video when **pause/resume** playing?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892520/ios-avplayer-cancel-buffering

Answer (score 5):

One way to do that would be to save your `AVURLAsset` to a variable (`tempAsset = player.playerItem.asset`), and then replace the `playerItem` in your player with nil. When you are ready to play it again, you can create a new `playerItem` from the asset that you saved previously.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and i used buffer limit to stop preloading in my code.
This works for me.

You can also try setting buffer limit to stop preloading video when you click on Pause or Resume.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: How do you set a buffer limit in code using AVFoundation?

Answer (score 0):

The duration the player should buffer media from the network ahead of the playhead to guard against playback disruption.

```
player.currentItem?.preferredForwardBufferDuration
```

When you work with `AVPlayerItem` you can set time interval for the buffer. Example:

```
AVPlayerItem(). preferredForwardBufferDuration = TimeInterval(exactly: 100)!
```

Comment: please explain your solution so that others can gain some insights into it.

Comment: You should write a little explanation to your code.